# Selected manual install and now grub can't find moddep files

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I recently re-built my PC and decided to re-install my OS'es.

I had Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04, now I'm installing Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.04.

I followed this guide:
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

I was not able to select "install alongside windows", so I did a manual install.

In grub, I now see:

```
*Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
```

I choose "Ubuntu" and I get:

```
starting version 219
could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/modules.dep.bin'
could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/modules.dep.bin'
[    2.661604] usb 2-1.17: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Gave up waiting for root device.  Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!   /dev/dsk/by/uuid/92c34803-4e28-89c7-78480f11df455 does not exist.
Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-9ubuntu1) built-in-shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't just stick with Ubuntu **14.04 LTS**?

Comment: @david6 I want the latest and greatest!

Comment: Well you will stop getting support for 15.04 in January 2016. You will have to upgrade to the next release or use the LTS which has support for 5 years.

Comment: But I can upgrade right?

Comment: Don't do anything until you boot Windows and make sure the NTFS partition is clean (as opposed of dirty, a `chkdsk /f` may be enough) and Windows is shutdown correctly (no hibernation, suspension, or any other variant). On the other hand, why wasn't a in-place upgrade not an option? You could just tell Ubuntu to upgrade and you wouldn't have this kind of troubles. BTW, why it's trying to load 3.16 kernel modules when obviously 15.04 use 3.19? This leads me to think that you are having scruff of 14.04 messing up your boot.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you reinstall it. Follow these steps for manual installation:

1. When you choose a partition for manual install, format it with ext4 and choose mount point as `/`.
2. Always install Grub on the partition, on which you are installing Ubuntu. This way, you can change boot flag to Windows in case anything goes wrong.
3. After the installation, don't change the boot flag to Ubuntu partition yet. Restart the system to see, if Windows is booted by default (just for making sure everything went all right).
4. Live-boot from your installation media and change the boot flag from Windows partition to Ubuntu partition.
5. Restart your system and choose Ubuntu.

Comment: I did you like you said. It seems to work fine now (It was like I said, just a corrupt ISO file when I created the linux USB).

I used GParted to set boot flag to the ubuntu partition, but when I'm in grub, I don't see windows 10. I only see Windows Recovery. Where's Windows 10? :S

Comment: type ' sudo update-grub ' in terminal and see if it detects windows 10.

Comment: nope, first install grub afesh by `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` followed by `update-grub`

Comment: Ok. It did detect it but it was also called "Windows recovery" so I googled and find a way to open the grub config and renamed it to simply "Windows  10".

Answer (score 1):

Your fstab seems to have messed up. I have heard that Windows 10 does some re-partitioning of the hard drive during it's install/upgrade. Why does Microsoft think it is the only OS around? Someone should teach Bill Gates about the term 'dual boot'.

Anyways grab a LiveCD of Ubuntu. Boot into the live environment and mount your Ubuntu installation.

Open a terminal and `cd` to the root of your Ubuntu. It should be somewhere in /media/

Edit your fstab:

```
sudo gedit etc/fstab
```

The first entry will be for the root filesystem. You need to correct it's UUID. You can list the UUIDs of all your partitions by:

```
sudo blkid -L
```

Make the change, save and reboot. It should fix the issue.

Comment: The fstab is correct, what you say with boot repair is just the nuke option, and not necessary on most cases.

Comment: @Braiam Yeah, I should probably remove it. Kernel is loading, udev has started. But I let it be there because maybe the boot repair fixes the fstab? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an IT professional but [Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) saved my back many times, especially when doing a clean install of a new LTS release. It's a live iso that automatically repairs GRUB (it may ask you one or two simple questions like "is it an external hard drive or not"). I read the GRUB info you posted. It says something about "/dev/dsk/by/uuid/92c34803-4e28-89c7-78480f11df455 does not exist" which usually means the Grub configuration file is bad. I had a similar problem when I installed Ubuntu Mate 14.04 LTS but [Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) solved that for me.

However, I do wonder too why you abandoned an LTS version? By the way, I used that installation guide too. It suggests creating an external home partition. This way you can reinstall Ubuntu and keep your application settings.

Hope it works out for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I'm currently trying something I never did, simply re-downloading the ISO file. Maybe it got corrupted or something.

Comment: You're right with that as you installed it recently. I would use a torrent over a simple download. It's faster and more reliable. I never got a md5sum mismatch with torrenting so far. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you create the bootable USB drive, make sure the downloaded ISO is not corrupt. Either via checksum or just use a torrent as that's less susceptible to data corruption, it seems.